# Vue-Select: How to save all entries as lower case items?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-select

I am using the [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/) library. How can I force input entries to make all characters lower case? Right now, when I type the word "Baseball" into the input field, the tag is saved as "Baseball". I would like all tags to only keep a lower case version of the entry such as "baseball".

I have a sandbox here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ranqmt?file=src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>Vue Select</h3>
    <v-select
      v-model="selected"
      taggable
      multiple
      :options="options"
      @input="setSelected"
    ></v-select>
    <br /><br />
    selected: <br />
    <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vSelect from 'vue-select';
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    'v-select': vSelect,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSelected(value) {
      console.log(value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

a - You could add a computed property which returns the lowercased version to use in whichever part of your app you need it to be.

```
computed: {
  selectedLowerCase() {
    return this.selected.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

b - if you are using this for something like an API call, then you can turn the variable(s) into lowercase before submitting.

c - if you want the variable to appear as lowercase even in the input field you need to add the `@input` action to your input field and point it to a function to lowercase your input

```
  methods: {
    setSelected(value) {
      this.selected = this.selected.toLowerCase();
      console.log(value);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Not sure why, but option 'c' and setting the `setSelected()` value gives me error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')`. Did that work for you?

Comment: I have not really used v-select, and do not know what type of input yours is, if the input type has a non string value, then the function will not work. if the value is supposed to be a string, then try changing the original value from `null` to an empty string `""`

Comment: i think it's possible that the docs for this is not updated for vue3. Could be error due to the way vue3 handles input/modelValue stuff